# Outlook Add-in (C#) - Is it possible to add a button to appointment reminder popup

Tags: c#, outlook, add-in

We have developed a nice form add-in for Outlook Appointment Items which shows the location of the meeting on graphical map. The question is whether it is possible to add a button to the standard calendar reminder popup. The typical example is the Skype plugin, which shows "join online" button, if the calendar entry contains a Skype link:

[image: Reminder popup]

A small example in C# would be enough, unfortunately i cannot find an API reference which would support it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no public API to do that.

Comment: Is it still true in 2022?

Comment: Yes, you still cannot do that.